# css placeholder line height not working on chrome. This is working fine in mozilla

Tags: css

```
.emailBox input.myInput[type="password"]::-webkit-input-placeholder
 {/* WebKit browsers */
 line-height: 46px;
 }
.emailBox input.myInput[type="password"]:-moz-placeholder
 { /* Mozilla  Firefox 4 to 18 */
 line-height: 46px;
 }
.emailBox input.myInput[type="password"]::-moz-placeholder 
 { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
 line-height: 46px;
 }
```

css placeholder line height not working on chrome and safari. This is working fine in mozilla

Comment: It just works, show a screenshot or jsfiddle preferably then

Comment: I do see the problem: a 46px high input field with a 46px line-height for a placeholder shows the placeholder in SeaMonkey, but not in Chromium. https://jsfiddle.net/htpav39h/3/ The solution might be to not use a line height at all; can you explain why you think you need one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.emailBox input.myInput#frmUserPassword::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
line-height: 35px;
}
.emailBox input.myInput#frmUserPassword:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla   Firefox 4 to 18 */
line-height: 46px;
}
.emailBox input.myInput#frmUserPassword::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
line-height: 46px;
}
.emailBox input.myInput#frmUserPassword:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
line-height: 40px;
}
```

Above css working fine for all devices. But chrome not showing in inspect element so this was confusing me. But all is good now. Above css is checked in Mac, Windows, Linux, Iphone, Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

It just works for me.

[image]

Like in here.

[image]

Comment: Oh, but there _are_ differences between your two screenshots. If you use the right metrics, the placeholder disappears from view altogether in Chrome. See [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htpav39h/3/).